# passing variable to the next page in php

Tags: php

i have this code below and i cannot seem to understand why the i cannot see $pId in the next page. i seem that he doesnt send the variable in $pId in profile.php please help

```
  <?php
        include 'config.php';
        include 'dbconnection.php';
session_start();

        if(isset($_REQUEST["pwd"]) && isset($_REQUEST["name"]))
        {
            $password = $_REQUEST['pwd'];
            $name = $_REQUEST['name'];

                    $checkUserPass = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM validPersonnel WHERE Passkey = '$password' and Name = '$name'", $conn);
                    if(mysql_num_rows($checkUserPass) == 1)
                    {   


                        $sql="SELECT PersonnelID FROM validPersonnel WHERE Passkey = :password and Name = :name";
                        $query=$db->prepare($sql);
                        $query->execute(array('name' => $name, 'password' => $password));
                        $row = $query->fetch();
                        $_SESSION['personnelId'] = $row['PersonnelID'];

                        header("Refresh: 1; url=profile/profile.php?p_id={$pId}");
                        echo "<br/><br/>";
                        echo "<script>alert('Logged In.')</script>";


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //  print_r($query);
                        echo "<br/><br/>";
                        echo "<script>alert('Wrong Password.')</script>";
                        header('Refresh: 1; url=personnelselect.php');
                    }
        }

        mysql_close($conn);
    ?>
```

the code below is the link where i pass the $pId

```
            if(isset($_SESSION['personnelId']))
            {
            $id = $_SESSION['personnelId'];
            $sqlLoader="Select Name from validpersonnel where PersonnelID = :id";
            $resLoader=$db->prepare($sqlLoader);
            $resLoader->execute(array('id' => $id));
            $row = $resLoader->fetch();
            echo $row['Name'];
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: You know about `session_start()` and `$_SESSION`, right?

Comment: Store variables in `$_SESSION` array or set some `GET` parameters for links.

Comment: Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\wamp\www\v1.2\login_pane\login_pane-personnelselect\profile\displaynamev1.php on line 3
Call Stack

Answer (score 0):

Almost all variables are destroyed when a script ends. I would recommend using a $_SESSION variable or passing the variables via $_GET.

For example to store the variable:

```
$_SESSION['pid'] = $pId;
```

To retrieve the variable:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['pid'])) $pId = $_SESSION['pid'];
```

Comment: Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\wamp\www\v1.2\login_pane\login_pane-personnelselect\profile\displaynamev1.php on line 3
Call Stack

Comment: Another script is already calling session_start(); So in this case you do not need to call it again.

Comment: Remove session_start() from that php, because it's redeclared.

Comment: i did and i didnt show the name of the valid personnel

Comment: Try and put session_start(); in the page you are passing the variable. See if that works. Maybe session_start is not being called on that page.

Comment: Make sure to put session_start(); near the top of the page.

Comment: Add this to your second page:

Comment: echo "ID is ".$_SESSION['personnelId']; 

Let see if it is a problem with the session or the SQL.